# Remove elements from object in Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an object

```js
let myObj = {"info1": "", "info2": "", "info3": "", ......}
```

Here I want to remove `info1` and `info2`. I tried `splice`, but it is throwing error. The `pop` method is also not working. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what errors you are getting.

Comment: is this an object or array?

Comment: The example you have provided is an object. Use delete operator to remove the desired properties.

Comment: That is an object. I think it will work out @andrewallen

Comment: @RajkumarKalaimani the thing you call an array in you question is an object `{"a":"a", "b":"b", "c":"c"}`, not an array `[a,b,c]`.

Comment: Thats an ```object``` so to delete any properties from object use ```delete property.myObject```. That might help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this various ways:

### Delete

```js
const data = { "info1": "", "info2": "", "info3": "" };

delete data.info1;
delete data.info2;

console.log(data);
```

### Filter

```js
const data = { "info1": "", "info2": "", "info3": "" };
const ignore = ['info1', 'info2'];

const copy = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([k, v]) => !ignore.includes(k)));

console.log(copy);
```

### Destructure

```js
const data = { "info1": "", "info2": "", "info3": "" };

const { info1, info2, ...copy } = data;

console.log(copy);
```